# Regex to replace a repeated integer with it's number of matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a compression algorithm that will replace all repeated zeros in a string, of at least 5 in a row, with the string `"z(#)"`.

For example:

```
"01100000210000000000000001"

"011z(5)21z(15)1"
```

I've been able to replace all occurrences of repeated zeros with a substring using the following but I can't figure out how to find the number of matches and replace it with `"z(#)"`

```
string.replace(/(0{5,})/g, "hi");
```

Is this possible to do using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is super-specific to your example regex, but just to demonstrate that the [replacement value parameter of `replace` will accept a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```
"01100000210000000000000001".replace(/0{5,}/g, function(matches) {
   return 'z(' + matches.length + ')';
})
```

Comment: The [current version of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5) (as of this comment) is still based on ECMAScript 5.  This question was not marked as an ECMAScript 6 question, and fat arrow syntax is only in ECMAScript 6 I believe.  Please either clarify the use of the `=>` operator in your answer or rewrite it to be runnable in the current version of JavaScript, please.

Comment: @JosephMarikle There’s no such thing as the current JavaScript _version_. ECMAScript 6 is the _current finished, released standard_ on which JavaScript is based on.

Comment: @Xufox Granted, it's a bit of a misnomer.  I just looked for a [breakdown of ECMAScript 6 support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and it looks like most browsers (and thus a greater part of applications that use JavaScript engines) now have a JavaScript "version"/engine that supports ES6 for the most part.  IE and mobile are still behind, but I guess I can stop pointing out ES6 Syntax in JavaScript answers now.  Thanks for the correction, Xufox.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String expression = "01100000210000000000000001";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0{5,})");       
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String match =matcher.group();
            expression = expression.replaceFirst(match,"Z("+match.length()+")");            
        }
```